# Error while trying to use java.util.ArrayList on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, arraylist

I'm trying to work with java.util.ArrayList in a Java project in Eclipse. It resolves funny on this IDE, contrary to what I'm used to on NetBeans. For example:

On NetBeans, I can create a Generic ArrayList simply as follows:

```
List<Bundle> bundles = new ArrayList();
```

However, on Eclipse, this is the structure, if I'm to successfully declare and initialize an ArrayList:

```
List bundles = (List) new ArrayList<Bundle>();
```

I'm forced to do a type casting, and the Generisation can only be done on the right side.

This, however, is not too bad, untill I try to call call some of the ArrayList methods, such as `bundles.add(bundle1);`. I get an error highlight on the method `add()`.

`dundles.` `Ctrl+space` gives me a 'No Default Proposals'

Have I got my IDE platform badly, or incompletely configured? What could be the problemo?

Thank you all in advance.

--- >

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
>   Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
>   Build id: 20150924-1200

--- >

> java version "1.8.0_60"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Comment: Are you sure you've imported `java.util.List` and not some other kind of `List` ?

Comment: Yes. Completely sure @Titus.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Bundle> bundles = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Bear in mind that in Java 8 this can be simplified to `List<Bundle> bundles = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: True!  I'm still learning all those updates.  I'll amend my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: With that I get the whole line (`List<Bundles> bundles = new ArrayList<Bundle>();`) highlighted as containing an error. Eclipse prompts me to 'Remove type arguments' and then to 'Add cast to List'.

Comment: Your Eclipse might have a bigger problem then, because I don't get the same error.

Comment: Although your eclipse and jre looks up-to-date, I would try updating them again.  I would also try deleting all the list-related imports you have for that class and re-adding the imports to make 100% sure you have the right arraylist and list imported (java.util.List and java.util.ArrayList).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    List<Bundle> bundles = new ArrayList<Bundle>();
```

This should be the syntactically correct way to do do it.

If this doesn't work, it may be an issue with Java. I believe that Java, at the runtime, contains information about the List's contents and components. So the List must know and have a component type when you create it.